# What is () => operator?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I came across this ajax call. It works perfectly fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/items/' + item.id,
    method: 'PUT',
    data: {item: item},
    success: () => {
        this.updateItems(item); 
    }
});
```

I did not get what `() =>` means. I used success: `function(){ }` but then it gives me an error

> "updateItems is not a function"

Comment: This is called an "arrow function", a new way to declare functions in es6. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is the MDN documentation, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions#t=201607230227390313154) is the new StackOverflow documentation!

Comment: Tha's an ES6 lambda function. The reason you are getting error with a normal function is because in lambdas, 'this' has a different scope.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still one concern. If its new way to declare function then going forward the old way function(){ } will not work  ?

Comment: @user2015 I don't see `function` going out of style any time soon. ;) If you read the answers below, or any of the documentation, you'll realize that these syntaxes are not completely equivalent, anyway. (If they were, you wouldn't receive the error that you do!)

Comment: @this-vidor - exactly if they are similar then I should not have got an error. By the way I will read all answers to fully understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct is called an arrow function. It has been introduced with the ES2015 standard and works similar the the `function() {}` syntax.

For more infos, [check the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Note that this syntax is not yet supported by all browsers, especially older versions, so you should look into [transpiling it into ES5 compliant JavaScript](https://babeljs.io/).

---

The reason why your attempt to transform it into a classic `function() {}` fails is that classic functions define their own `this` value, while arrow functions use the `this` value of the surrounding function. This is why `this.updateItems` cannot be found anymore.

To resolve this, bind the function context manually:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/items/' + item.id,
    method: 'PUT',
    data: {item: item},
    success: function() {
        this.updateItems(item); 
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: For this to be a proper answer, please answer OP's question about the error they are receiving. This results from the difference in how `this` is scoped/bound using arrow syntax.

Comment: @this-vidor Done! :-)

Comment: Nice! (The downvote wasn't mine.)

Comment: Thanks TimoSta. It gave me more insight about arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Arrow Function, and is like an anonymous function that also binds `this`.  When you switched it to a function(), the `this` was bound to something else, hence the error.

Edit:

If you still want to use a more traditional syntax, then use:

```
function(){/*...*/}.bind(this)
```

Which will ensure you're bound to the correct object.

Comment: **Explain** the difference! "Something else" is not helpful.

Comment: @this-vidor I thought I did. The key to his error was the way that binding differed, which I stated.

Comment: JavaScript is deterministic. "Something else" is a very specific something in this case. What is `this` bound to when using the `function` syntax? Your edit is much more helpful, but still sloppy.

Comment: @this-vidor no, the point was that it *wasn't* bound to what he was expecting. What it actually *was* bound to makes no difference.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks seairth. I am not able to mark this as an answer.